# jquery prevent last checkbox being unchecked with change event

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of checkboxes:

```
<form id="settingsForm">

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_daily">
<label>Daily</label> 

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_weekly">
<label>Weekly</label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_monthly">
<label>Monthly</label>

</form>
```

And a `change` event that checks if any inputs in my form change:

```
$("#settingsForm")
    .find("input")
    .change(function(){

});
```

This works in terms of detecting changes. However I want to make it so that the user must leave at least 1 of the checkboxes given in the HTML above checked.

So I can do a test inside the `change` as follows:

```
if ($('.form-check-input:checked').length == 0) {
    console.log('You must select at least 1 checkbox');
}
```

Again, this works. But the problem is that it leaves no checkboxes checked. The form is saved via ajax so it's not as though I can disable a Submit button, or some other UI element that stops the user getting things into this state. I presume the correct way is therefore to not allow the user to uncheck the checkbox if it's the last one that was checked?

What do I have to put in here to make sure that the clicked element remains checked? I tried doing `console.log(this)` and it outputs the HTML for the element I clicked on.

However I can't target it, e.g. `$(this).attr('checked', true);` doesn't do anything?

jquery 3.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe the same as your original code, but use `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

> [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) - As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

```js
$('#settingsForm input').on('change', function() {
  var len = $('#settingsForm input:checked').length;
  if (len === 0) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    console.log('You must select at least 1 checkbox');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="settingsForm">

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_daily">
  <label>Daily</label>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_weekly">
  <label>Weekly</label>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_monthly">
  <label>Monthly</label>

</form>
```

Comment: This works. Is there any explanation you can give as to why `prop()` works instead of `attr()` here? I have other things in the code which are using `attr()` to check/uncheck and these work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the change event on the `.form-check-input` class, and inside that event you can check wheter if the checkboxes are "empty" or not.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on("change", function(){
  var noChecked = $('.form-check-input:checked').length;
  
  if(noChecked === 0){
    console.log("0 checkboxes are checked");
  } else {
    console.log("checkboxes ok", noChecked);
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="settingsForm">

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_daily">
<label>Daily</label> 

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_weekly">
<label>Weekly</label>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="emailFrequency_monthly">
<label>Monthly</label>

</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```